# Creating shopping history

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I already made a simple shop, where user can fill up balance in his profile and after that can buy some digital content.
Now I need to save all purchases in a separate model, where I can see, who bought what and when...
But I don't understand, how to save that info in model after user purchased item...
That is what I have now...

User model with balance and withdraw function:

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    class Meta():
        db_table = 'userprofile'

    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    user_picture = models.ImageField(upload_to='users', blank=False, null=False, default='users/big-avatar.jpg')
    user_balance = models.DecimalField(default=0, max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)

    def withdraw(self, amount):
        self.user_balance = self.user_balance - amount

    def can_purchase_amount(self, amount):
        if amount <= self.user_balance:
            return True

User.profile = property(lambda u: UserProfile.objects.get_or_create(user=u) [0])
```

The `orderstatus` app, where I made a model `OrderHistory` for order history:

```
class OrderHistory(models.Model):
    class Meta():
        db_table = 'order_history'

    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    article = models.ForeignKey(Article)
    purchase_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

After User hit "BUY", he launched `POST` with `action`, that follows to `views.py` in `orderstatus` app:

```
def checkoutstatus(request, article_id):

    user_profile = UserProfile.objects.get(user=request.user)
    article = Article.objects.get(id=article_id)

    if user_profile.can_purchase_amount(article.article_cost):

        user_profile.withdraw(article.article_cost)
        user_profile.save()

        article.article_users.add(request.user)

    return redirect('/articles/get/%s' % article_id)
```

So, that view checks is User have enough money in his `user_balance` and if it is, make a `withdraw`. So, I need to save that purchase in `OrderHistory` model if purchase done... Never do such tasks before... How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should probably add creating OrderHistory object like this:

> OrderHistory.objects.create(user=request.user, article=article)

```
def checkoutstatus(request, article_id):

    user_profile = UserProfile.objects.get(user=request.user)
    article = Article.objects.get(id=article_id)

    if user_profile.can_purchase_amount(article.article_cost):

        user_profile.withdraw(article.article_cost)
        user_profile.save()

        article.article_users.add(request.user)

        OrderHistory.objects.create(user=request.user, article=article)

    return redirect('/articles/get/%s' % article_id)
```

Comment: Ohh... Doesn't think, that some things so simple sometimes...))) Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In my app I have written a view

```
def orderhistory(request):
order_histroy = Order.objects.filter(user=request.user)
template = "users/orders.html"
context = {
    "order_histroy": order_histroy
}
return render(request, template, context)
```